# QiBuild/CMake cannot not find BOOST_FILESYSTEM

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, nao-robot

I'm trying to build the C++ examples from Aldebaran like helloworld and sayhelloworld, but qiBuild keeps saying it cannot not find BOOST_FILESYSTEM. Boost is installed and working, I tested it with some other projects in Visual Studio.

This is the error after running `qibuild configure -c atom1145`:

```
[WARN ]:  Nested worktrees detected:
d:\ald_sdk\naoqi-sdk-1.14.5-win32-vs2010\doc\examples is already in a worktree
(in d:\ald_sdk)

Current build worktree: d:\ald_sdk\naoqi-sdk-1.14.5-win32-vs2010\doc\examples
Using toolchain: atom1145
Build type: Debug
* (1/1) Configuring sayhelloworld
-- Using qibuild 3.7.1
-- Binary: sayhelloworld
CMake Error at D:/Programs/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find BOOST_FILESYSTEM (missing: BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/Programs/CMake/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:374 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/find.cmake:361 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/find.cmake:269 (_qi_call_fphsa)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/modules/boostutils.cmake:39 (export_lib)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/modules/boost_filesystem-config.cmake:9 (boost_flib)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/internal/uselib.cmake:80 (find_package)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/internal/uselib.cmake:94 (_qi_use_lib_get_deps)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/internal/uselib.cmake:94 (_qi_use_lib_get_deps)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/internal/uselib.cmake:94 (_qi_use_lib_get_deps)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/internal/uselib.cmake:94 (_qi_use_lib_get_deps)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/internal/uselib.cmake:158 (_qi_use_lib_get_deps)
  d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/stage.cmake:246 (_qi_use_lib_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (qi_use_lib)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/ALD_SDK/naoqi-sdk-1.14.5-win32-vs2010/doc/examples/core/sayhelloworld/build-atom1145/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/ALD_SDK/naoqi-sdk-1.14.5-win32-vs2010/doc/examples/core/sayhelloworld/build-atom1145/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
[ERROR]:  ConfigureFailed Error occurred when configuring project sayhelloworld
```

After Boost compiled, I got the following paths:

```
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    D:/Programs/boost_1_57_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    D:\Programs\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib
```

These are not the default path's and I guess that's causing some problems.

In the CMakeCache.txt I found that the Boost entries were "cleared":

```
//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for BOOST.
BOOST_DIR:PATH=d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/modules

//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for BOOST_FILESYSTEM.
BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DIR:PATH=d:/Programs/Python27/share/cmake/qibuild/modules

//Cleared.
BOOST_FILESYSTEM_EXECUTABLE:STRING=

//Cleared.
BOOST_FILESYSTEM_EXECUTABLE_DEBUG:STRING=

//Cleared.
Boost_DEFINITIONS:STRING=

//Cleared.
Boost_EXECUTABLE:STRING=

//Cleared.
Boost_EXECUTABLE_DEBUG:STRING=

//Boost filesystem library (debug)
Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND

//Boost filesystem library (release)
Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE:FILEPATH=Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND

//Path to a file.
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=D:/ALD_SDK/naoqi-sdk-1.14.5-win32-vs2010/include

//Cleared.
Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS:STRING=

//Cleared.
Boost_LIBRARIES:STRING=
```

I tried to add some variables to the CMakeLists.txt like this, but it didn't help:

```
set(Boost_DEBUG true)
set(BOOST_ROOT "D:/Programs/boost_1_57_0")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "D:/Programs/boost_1_57_0/boost")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "D:/Programs/boost_1_57_0/stage/lib")
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution from the Aldebaran support:

It seems to have some incompatibilty between the NAOqi 1.14.5 C++ SDK for windows and the latest version of qibuild.

On my side I have tested with the latest version of qibuild and it gave me the same error as yours.

I will let our team now to update the documentation.
In the mean time I can propose you a workaround, ie, uninstall qibuild by using
`pip uninstall qibuild` and reinstall a version that is working with the NAOqi 1.14.5 C++ SDK for windows

```
pip install qibuild==3.5.1
```

This one should be working.